# SQL Server query plan using hash vs streamaggregate

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[caja]
(
    [orden] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ejercicio] [int] NOT NULL,
    [numero] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tipo] [char](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_caja_tipo]  DEFAULT ('N'),
    [inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [final] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_caja] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([orden] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX___caja__ejercicio_numero] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ejercicio] ASC, [numero] ASC, [tipo] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX___caja__tipo_inicial] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([tipo] ASC, [inicial] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[holograma]
(
    [orden] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [taller] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tipo] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [final] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fecha] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_holograma] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([tipo] ASC, [inicial] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tally]
(
    [N] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tally_N] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([N] ASC)
)
```

`Tally` table contains one million records from N=1 to 1,000,000

`Caja` table contains a list of valid values to insert into `holograma` table,

Example:

```
orden   | ejercicio | numero    | tipo  | inicial   | final     
888     | 2015      | 74        | R     | 50144001  | 50144660  
889     | 2015      | 75        | R     | 50144661  | 50146660
```

and `holograma`:

```
taller  | tipo  | inicial   | final     | total | fecha
160     | A     | 50144651  | 50144750  | 100   | 15/04/2015 <--values of two caja's
missing data
49      | A     | 50144826  | 50145025  | 200   | 15/04/2015
```

I'm trying to get the missing data. Using the example must show me from 50144751 to 50144825, counting 75 numbers.

The problem is with the count aggregate, it's taking to much time when I delimit the values. This is my query

```
declare @tipo nchar(1)
    ,@numero int
    ,@ejercicio int
    ,@largo int
;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

select @tipo='A' , @numero=176;
select @ejercicio=2015, @largo=10000000;

with
c as ( /* La caja a buscar */ 
    select tipo, numero, inicial / @largo as serie, inicial as cInicial, final as cFinal, total, entregados, orden as cOrden
    from caja
    where 1=1
    and (tipo=@tipo)
    and (numero=@numero)
    and ejercicio=@ejercicio
)
, h as ( /* Los hologramas que corresponden a esa caja */
    select serie, inicial - (serie*@largo) as hInicial, final - (serie*@largo) as hFinal
    , h1.orden as hOrden
    , cOrden, cInicial, cFinal
    from holograma as h1
    inner join c
    on h1.tipo=c.tipo
    and h1.inicial>=40000000
    and (h1.inicial between c.cInicial and c.cFinal or h1.final between c.cInicial and c.cFinal)
)
, t2 as ( /* se usa para corregir  */
    select n  
    from tally 
    inner join c on  (n between cInicial- (serie*@largo) and cFinal - (serie*@largo))   
)
, t as ( /* Generar los números individuales según la ENTREGA de hologramas */
    select serie,n  as nHolograma
    , hOrden, h.cOrden
    from t2
    inner join h on (n between hInicial and hFinal) 
)
, e as ( /* cuantos hologramas por caja se han entregado. este se usa para corregir tabla caja */
    select cOrden, COUNT(nHolograma) as totalG
    from t
    group by cOrden
)
select * from e
```

And the query plan is

https://pastee.org/kpt3t

but if I change in the "t" subquery from "t2" table to "tally" table

```
, t as ( /* Generar los números individuales según la ENTREGA de hologramas */
    select serie,n  as nHolograma
    , hOrden, cOrden
    from tally, h
    where 1=1
    and (n between hInicial and hFinal) 
)
```

the query is almost instant. this is the query plan

https://pastee.org/hfpnz

The difference is the StreamAggregate using tally table to Hash using t2 subquery (line 196) .

I use the "t2"-subquery to delimit to the values of the current caja.
Why does the aggregate change? It's one minute of difference. 1 second with delimiting the numbers to 1:02 minutes delimiting.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the issue is here. I would recommend though that you read both of these articles. You are using the NOLOCK hint judiciously [well read uncommitted which is the same thing but for every table] (http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) and you are using the old style joins which went out of favor nearly 30 years ago (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Sean Lange - Yes, I know that are old join, but are really simple. It does not affect the result in this case. But you make me thing and and change it. I'll check about the NOLOCK.

Comment: The most important part of my comment as it relates to your question is the first sentence in my first reply. What is the actual issue here?

Comment: It's taking to much time to do a count to no more of 2000 rows. A "caja" has 2000 sheet of paper (by example from number 1 to 2000), from a caja we sell the sheets, I store the sell in "holograma" (example from caja-1 we sell from 1-900 to A, 1001 to 2020 to B - last 20 are from another caja), but maybe we miss some sheets like 901-1000 in this example, I need to check that all sells are registred. Of caja-1 we miss 100 sheets, so the count must say 1900.